# How to access data inside the plugin.xml?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am currently developing a **Java RCP** with **Eclipse RCP** which has a *plugin.xml* where one can find information like *ID*, *version*, *Name*, *plattform*, and so on....

Now, my question is, whether it is possible to somehow access the *plugin.xml* from my java code. Is it for example possible to load the *ID* into a therefor created variable?

**edit**
I want to access the *ID* you can find when you open the *plugin.xml* file with the plug-in manifest editor. I tried the approach with *Platform.getBundle("plugin.xml")*, but I only received an object refering to *null*.

**edit2**
I also tried *Platform.getProduct().getId();* but it seems *getProduct()* also returns *null*. Does anyone have a clue why those two approaches mentioned above do not work? Or does anyone have a proper solution for accessing the *ID*?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
kain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Platform.getBundle("symbolic.name") to get the reference to your plugin. You can get version number and id from the Bundle object. 
http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/org/osgi/framework/Bundle.html